# How to calculate the amount of times Ackerman's Function calls itself?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long int A(int, int);

int main()
{
    int m, n;
        cout << "Enter two numbers for Ackerman's Function." << endl;
        cin >> m >> n;

        cout << A(m, n) << endl;
}

long int A(int m, int n)
{
    if(m == 0)
    {
        return n+1;
    }
    else if(m > 0 && n == 0)
    {
        return A(m-1,1);
    }
    else if(m > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        int temp = A(m,n-1);
        return A(m-1, temp);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple code of an Ackerman's function. I am wondering how many times does this Ackerman's function calls itself as a function of n, if m is a constant? My brain exploded trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a count global variable to find out

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long int A(int, int);
int count=0;

int main()
{
    int m, n;
        cout << "Enter two numbers for Ackerman's Function." << endl;
        cin >> m >> n;

        cout << A(m, n) << endl;
        count << " Ackerman's Function runs " << count << " times.";
}

long int A(int m, int n)
{   
    count++;
    if(m == 0)
    {
        return n+1;
    }
    else if(m > 0 && n == 0)
    {
        return A(m-1,1);
    }
    else if(m > 0 && n > 0)
    {
        int temp = A(m,n-1);
        return A(m-1, temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra parameter of type `int&` to your `A` function:

```
long int A(int m, int n, int& count)
{   
    count++;
```

And update the prototype, and the recursive calls to match.

In your main function:

```
int count = 0;
cout << A(m, n, count) << endl;
cout << "A calls: " << count << endl;
```

This avoids globals, which are problematic.